# Set Cache Control in request header doesn't work

Tags: http, web, caching, http-headers

According to [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#page-22)

> The "max-age" request directive indicates that the client is unwilling
> to accept a response whose age is greater than the specified number of
> seconds

So I tried setting up a small app to test it out. I set the `Cache-Control: 'max-age=5'` in the request and `Cache-Control: 'max-age=10'` in the response. If I understand the above sentence correctly, every request I make after 5 seconds should receive a brand new response. But after 5 seconds, I still receive the "old response". Am I missing anything?

[image]

Here are code:

Client:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="onClick()">
        Fetch
    </button>
    <div class="response-container">
    </div>
    
    <script>
        const onClick = async () => {
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/hello', {
                headers: {
                    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=5'
                }
            });
            const result = await response.json();
            console.log('result', result)
            // create a div and append to div with class .response-container
            const div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = result.message;
            document.querySelector('.response-container').appendChild(div);
        }
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Server:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());

let requestIdx = 1;
app.get("/hello", function (req, res) {
    // set cache control headers to expire in 10 seconds
    res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=10");
    res.send({
        message: "Hello World" + requestIdx++,
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: Where is the "old response" coming from?  I don't see any caching mechanism in your server code.

Comment: Although it occurs to me that you may be trying to bypass the browser caching. If that is the case, I doubt it will work. It looks like the max-age is supposed to be enforced by the server.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I set the Cache-Control to the response header. It will specify that the request to /hello should return the cache response which has an age is less than 10 seconds.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller if it's the case I doubt the example from the link I attached at the beginning of my question. I think that setting the cache-control in the request header should have a higher priority than in the response. I tried setting max-age=0 and it worked but any value greater than 0 seems to have no effect

Comment: Your interpretation of RFC 7234 looks correct to me, the issue here is probably just that browser caches are weird and aren't necessarily fully compliant. If it's a browser cache issue, it would interesting to try your code in all the major browsers to see if there is any difference in behavior.

Answer (score -1):

So, as per your question I guess whatever you've passed from server it would work. In case of cache control there's nothing needs to be done from client. It should always come as part of response header not request header.

Comment: But I don't think the option in the request header is there for no reason. I think it must have some effects.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).